# Call Instagram API without ACCESS_TOKEN

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Instagram recently change their API so it does not use client_id anymore but instead access_token.

I just want to get a list of instagram pictures that I have and put it on my website.

This is my previous `ajax` call using `jsonp`

`'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'+_instagram._id+'/media/recent/?client_id='+_instagram._clientId`

How do I do it now with `access_token`? I don't want a visitor of my website to log in into instagram everytime just to view my instagram pictures that will be available on my website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I get your question correctly, you want to fetch your own recent media that you have posted on Instagram using the new API endpoints using an access token.

So, the solution to this is pretty simple. You don't need your visitors to log in their Instagram every time to view your media on Instagram.

**Using Access Token(Using server side explicit method, preferred):**

- *Request Access Code:*

  ```
  var redirect_uri = "&redirect_uri="<REDIRECT-URI>,
      scope = "&scope=basic",
      response_type = "&response_type=code",
      url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=" + <CLIENT-ID> + redirect_uri + response_type + scope;
  ```
- *Exchange CODE for token:*
  Extract the code from `http://your-redirect-uri?code=CODE` and exchange this code to get the access token using server side method like cURL (preferred)

  - Use the endpoint: `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token`.
  - Pass the following parameters,

    - **client_id**
    - **client_secret**
    - **grant_type** as "authorization_code"
    - **redirect_uri**
    - **code**

**Without Using Access Token(Using implicit method):**

- *Request Access Token:*
  Use `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token`
- *Get Access Token:*
  Extract token using `http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

---

*Fetch your published media:*
Use endpoint as `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=<ACCESS-TOKEN>` (you can pass optional parameters like count if required)

---

---

Here your visitors don't need to log in their accounts. Once you have the link, save them in your database so you don't have to log in every time.

Hope it helps!

Comment: What, if the access_token expires?

Comment: @leFake, you have to ask the users to log in again and repeat the process above